# My speakers and audio jacks suddenly stopped working // Error: Failed to play test tone

Tags: windows, laptop, audio, drivers, speakers

I basically don't know what caused the issue! My laptop was on hibernate, I turned it back on, connected my headphones and I had no audio. I removed the headphones and still had no audio. Restarted the PC, had no audio. I uninstalled the audio driver in the Device Manager and reinstalled it, had no audio. I don't know what happened to my laptop's audio! PLEASE HELP!

I also get this error while trying to test my audio device:

[image]

### My Laptop

[Dell Alienware 17R5](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/alienware-17-gaming-laptop/spd/alienware-17-laptop)

### What I've tried so far:

I have basically tried every solution suggested in these websites:

1. [WindowsReport: Failed to play test tone on Windows 10? Here’s a fix](https://windowsreport.com/failed-to-play-sound-test-tone-windows-10/#:%7E:text=your%20audio%20device-,If%20you%27re%20frequently%20getting%20Failed%20to%20play%20sound%20test,choose%20Disable%20from%20the%20menu.)
2. [DriverEasy: Easy to Fix “Failed to play test tone” Error](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solved-failed-to-play-test-tone/)

Comment: What happens if you disable those exclusive mode checkboxes, and/or lower the quality of the test tone? Does the audio work without the headphones attached?

Comment: Can you see your audio devices listed?

Comment: Do you have sound under any condition? internal or external?

Comment: Sorry for responding late -- If I disable `exclusive mode` it won't fix. Lowering the quality of the test tone won't help either. Headphones attached or removed doesn't matter, it doesn't play any tone -- Yeah, I see my audio device listed like normal -- I don't have any sound under any condition right now!